# Set types on useState React Hook with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm migrating a React with TypeScript project to use hooks features (React v16.7.0-alpha), but I cannot figure out how to set typings of the destructured elements.

Here is an example:

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
}
...
const [user, setUser] = useState({name: 'Jon'});
```

I want to force `user` variable to be of type `IUser`. My only successful trial, is doing it in two phases: Typing, then initializing:

```
let user: IUser;
let setUser: any;
[user, setUser] = useState({name: 'Jon'});
```

But I'm sure there is a better way. Also, `setUser` should be initialized as a function that takes a `IUser` as input, and returns nothing.

Also, worth noting that using `const [user, setUser] = useState({name: 'Jon'});` without any initialization works fine, but I would like to take advantage of TypeScript to force type checking on init, especially if it depends on some props.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 617, accepted):

Use this

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>({name: 'Jon'});
```

See the [Corresponding Type in DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/942c50bb4d57679ca1dcb210f4984b41e7bbfdbb/types/react/v17/index.d.ts#L920)

Comment: This works, but seems totally insensitive to what's provided in place of `IUser`. I can put just about anything there and subsequent uses of `setUser` are passed by type checking.

Comment: @orome No, you can't put anything there, you can only put there an object that is compatible with `IUser`, i.e. has the same properties. It's called duck typing.

Comment: Do you how to do the same when my state variable is an array of objects?

Comment: @JoãoMarcosGris `type MyType = MyObj[]; ` then `useState<MyType>`

Comment: so underneath React's hood, it's using these types from DefinitelyTyped?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev - what about the types for `[user, setUser]`?   ... aren't we missing out on type-safety if we don't type them?

Comment: @JoeyBaruch No, we aren't :-) Just try it. Then look at the type definition, and you'll see that `useState` returns a well-typed tuple, that is assigned to `[user, setUser]` and it's not hard for TypeScript to understand that the variables should be of the same types as the tuple constituents. Don't know if I cleared things up or confused you further.

Answer (score 50):

First `useState` takes a generic, which will be your IUser. If you then want to pass around the second destructured element that is returned by `useState` you will need to import Dispatch. Consider this extended version of your example that has a click handler:

```
import React, { useState, Dispatch } from 'react';

interface IUser {
  name: string;
}

export const yourComponent = (setUser: Dispatch<IUser>) => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>({name: 'Jon'});

    const clickHander = (stateSetter: Dispatch<IUser>) => {
        stateSetter({name : 'Jane'});
    }

    return (
         <div>
            <button onClick={() => { clickHander(setUser) }}>Change Name</button>
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000308/how-to-add-type-notation-to-react-usestate).

Answer (score 4):

You could also declare the initial state before and then be able to call it any time you want:

```
type User = typeof initUser;
const initUser = {name: 'Jon'}
...
const [user, setUser] = useState<User>(initUser);
```

About I interface prefixes: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/styleguide/styleguide.html#interface

Answer (score 1):

https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/hooks/

```
// import useState next to FunctionComponent
    import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';
    
    // our components props accept a number for the initial value
    const Counter:FunctionComponent<{ initial?: number }> = ({ initial = 0 }) => {
      // since we pass a number here, clicks is going to be a number.
      // setClicks is a function that accepts either a number or a function returning
      // a number
      const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(initial);
      return <>
        <p>Clicks: {clicks}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setClicks(clicks+1)}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => setClicks(clicks-1)}>-</button>
      </>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Form {
    id: NullNumber = null;
    name = '';

    startTime: NullString = null;
    endTime: NullString = null;

    lunchStart: NullString = null;
    lunchEnd: NullString = null;

    [key: string]: string | NullNumber;
}

export const EditDialog: React.FC = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState<Form>(new Form());


    const inputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const element = e.target;
        setForm((form: Form) => {
            form[element.name] = element.value;
            return form;
        })
    }
    return (
        <Box pt={3}>
            <TextField
                required
                name="name"
                label="Наименование"
                defaultValue={form.name}
                onChange={inputChange}
                fullWidth
            />
        </Box>
    );
}
```