# How to add type notation to `React.useState`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using React 16.8.3 with hooks, currently I want to type `React.useState`

```
type Mode = 'confirm' | 'deny'  
type Option = Number | null

const [mode, setMode] = React.useState('confirm')
const [option, setOption] = React.useState(100)
```

With my current code, `mode` is of type `string`, when instead I want it of type `Mode`. Same issue with `Option`.

How to add type notation to `React.useState`?

Answer (score 10):

`React.useState` uses a generic, so you can add type notation to it in this in this way:

```
const [mode, setMode] = React.useState<Mode>('confirm')
const [option, setOption] = React.useState<Option>(100)
```

Just for information ... type definition of `React.useState`:

`function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];`