# Typescript error type not assign able to state - usestate

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am new to type script and I am trying to set the state in react using use state hook and type script.

```
const intialState: State ={
    items: [],
    value: "",
    error: null
}

const [data, setData]= useState([intialState]);

return (
    <>
        {
            data.items.map(x) => (
                //my html component to be displayed.
            )
        }
    </>
)
```

but I am getting the below error.
Can any one tell me.

1. Is it valid to set an object inside a usestate like I have done?
2. Why I am getting the typescript error?

[image]

Comment: What does your State type look like? The error was basically saying your State type(interface, class) does not have a property called items

Comment: actually I an trying to crate a new state as empty object so what type shall i define there? is object a valid type?

Comment: Can we see how `State` look like?

Comment: **See Also**: [Set types on useState React Hook with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53650468/1366033)

Answer (score 3):

First, we should check if there is an interface mismatch between `State`, and the `initialState` object. It will help if you can post the type definition of `State`.

In addition, you should supply the `useState` hook with the generic type parameter of `State[]`

```
const [data, setData]= useState<State[]>([intialState]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify type for useState. Since its an array of your state object you can write it like

```
const [data, setData]= useState<State[]>([intialState]);
```

Also make sure you define a type for your state's object

```
interface ErrorType {
   status: Number // more keys and their types here
}
interface MyDataType {
  items: ItemType[],
  error: ErrorType | null,
  value: string,
}
```

post that you can use it with useState like

```
const [data, setData]= useState<MyDataType[]>([intialState]);
```

Your data is an array of objects and when you update the state you need to merge the values. For that you can use functional setState

```
var updatedDataObj = { items: ["a","b","c"], error: "404", value: "xyx", };
setData(prevData => [...prevData, updatedDataObj]);
```

Comment: Thanks your your response can you please show me what is the syntax to setData with multiple objects.
var updatedDataObj = {
  items: ["a","b","c"],
  error: "404",
  value: "xyx",
};
setData(updatedDataObj);

is this correct?

Comment: Do you want to merge the objects or just replace them. Also data is an array of object so I am assuming you want to add more objects to it. Is that correct? Or do you just want to store an object in state instead of an array of objects?

Comment: yes...I want to add more object to that .
So basically I am trying to convert https://codesandbox.io/embed/ypyxr11109 this example into a reusable component using usestate hook

Comment: I updated my answer according to that. Please check

Comment: Can you please provide a small snippet for the above example or a fiddle using usestate.

Comment: I couldnt find any change in this fiddle codesandbox.io/embed/ypyxr11109 – have you done any chagnes here?

Comment: Ohh I think I didn't save it. Let me update it again

Comment: I had to make a new one. https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cloud-h270z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi at this line setState(prev => ({
          ...prev,
          items: [...prev.items, prev.value],
          value: ""
        }));

I am getting an error in my code as argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type set state action.

Can you please tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this was what you tried to achieve. Make sure you define your State type correctly, not importing from some other packages

```
interface State {
    items: any[];
    value: string;
    error: string | null;
}


const MyComponent: (props) => {
    const intialState: State ={
        items: [],
        value: "",
        error: null
    }
    const [data, setData] = useState(intialState)


return (
   <>
        {
            data.items.map(x) => (
                //my html component to be displayed.
            )
        }
    </>
    )
}
```