# useState with interface- react native typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, use-state

there is a way to use useState with an interface type?

This is what i'm tryint to do :

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null);

[...]

.then((responseJson) => {
            var movie: Movie = {
                id : id,
                title: responseJson.original_title,
                backdrop: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + responseJson.backdrop_path,
                note: responseJson.vote_average,
                numberNote: responseJson.vote_count,
                year: responseJson.release_date,
                runtime: responseJson.runtime,
                genre: responseJson.genres,
                plot: responseJson.overview,
            };
            setMovie(movie);
        })
```

But there is error on type.

My interface:

```
interface Movie {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    backdrop: string;
    note: number;
    numberNote: number,
    year: number,
    runtime: number,
    genre: {id: number, name: string}[],
    plot: string
}
```

according to this post : [Set types on useState React Hook with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650468/set-types-on-usestate-react-hook-with-typescript).

I can try to do something like that :

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie>({id: 0,
        title: "",
        backdrop: "",
        note: 0,
        numberNote: 0,
        year: 0,
        runtime: 0,
        genre: [{id: 0, name: ""}],
        plot: ""});
```

But it doesn't look clean and I don't think this is the good solution to put random value in the first state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set types on useState React Hook with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650468/set-types-on-usestate-react-hook-with-typescript)

Comment: yes and no... I will update my post to explain why

Comment: you can use a union type <Movie|null>(null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can imply state type in the following way:

```js
const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie|null>(null);
```