# Converting from React.js to React.tsx Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx, react-typescript

I am trying to follow a tutorial to learn react in type script. However when I build my solution I get and error.
Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const DataFetching = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setPosts(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(post => (<li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataFetching;
```

the error I am getting

```
TypeScript error in src/DataFetching.tsx(21,43):
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339
```

I am following the following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYFYF2GnMy8 . Any help or guidance is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set types on useState React Hook with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650468/set-types-on-usestate-react-hook-with-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always specify the `type` of the state variable. In this case, you are using an array of Posts. So you must create a Post interface and use that type in `useState`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface Post {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

const DataFetching = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setPosts(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(post => (<li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataFetching;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add type to `useState` explicitly. When you provide empty array typescript infer it's type as `never[]`.

`const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post>([]);`

Comment: Do you know why it infers it's type as `never` if not provided or if empty array is provided?

Comment: Empty array is `never[]`, because typescript doesn't have information about items, so it assumes it as always empty array. Alternative is pretty much only `any[]` or `unknown[]`, but it's not safe, so it's disabled in strict typescript. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8944