# How to use useState hook in React with typescript correctly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to make a login form in react with typescript. But setEmail method is not accepting value. It says Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'. What should I do to solve it?

[image]

Comment: You need to add a default string value to the hook above. `[email,setEmail] = useState('')`

Comment: **See Also**: [Set types on useState React Hook with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53650468/1366033)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set a **string type** for it

**Explicit way**:

```js
const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('')
```

*or* **Implicit way**:

```js
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
```

*or* if you want to set **number type**

```js
const [inputNumber, setInputNumber] = useState<number>(0);
```

then in `jsx`, do it this way

```
<input
  type="number"
  value={inputNumber}
  onChange={(val) => {
    //Some ways to do this
    setInputNumber(Number(val.target.value));
    setInputNumber(+val.target.value);
    setInputNumber(parseInt(val.target.value,0));
  }}
/>
```

[see more examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-typescript-forked-zzifj?file=/src/index.tsx:379-638)

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to use generic in this case with `useState` hook

**simple case**

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("")
```

**complex case**

- declare an interface

```
     interface IUser{
        email:string
        }
```

- make `useState` generic

```
     const [email, setEmail] = useState<IUser>({email: ''})
```

you can see [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ba2bb0f/types/react/index.d.ts#L916)

Answer (score 1):

Without any initial argument, the type of `email` and `setEmail` will be undefined.

```
const [email, setEmail]: [undefined, (value: ((prevState: undefined) => undefined) | undefined) => void] = useState();
```

So the first step is to enforce email to be a string by either using `useState("")` or even better `useState<string>("")`.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the useState with an empty string will solve.

useState can infer the type based on your initialState, thats why initialize with empty string will solve your case.

useState without initialState will be undefined, so your type and state is undefined.

If you want your state to have an more complex type, you need to pass a initialState with defined type:

```
const initialState: TYPE = {
  // ...
};
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
```

or

Pass the type to useState without set type to initialState, like: `useState<TYPE>(initialState);`