# Setting type on useState in Reactjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types

I'm trying to make my life easier by using type-specific objects in my javascript react project (typescript is unfortunately not an option). This is the code snippet that is causing the issue:

`const [projectsList, setProjectsList] = useState<Project>(testProject);`

And my model looks like:

```
export class Project {
    constructor(id, name, pm, projectType, start, end, expectedEnd, state, progress, publishDate, wave ) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.pm = pm;
      this.projectType = projectType;
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
      this.expectedEnd = expectedEnd;
      this.state = state;
      this.progress = progress;
      this.publishDate = publishDate;
      this.wave = wave;
    }
}
```

Without even sending it an object I'm getting this error in the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: boolean false is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Is this not the correct way to ensure type specificity in Javascript React projects?

I'm getting my info from these resources:

- [Set types on useState React Hook with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650468/set-types-on-usestate-react-hook-with-typescript) (I'm aware it says typescript but it was a starting point)
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ba2bb0f/types/react/index.d.ts#L916 (obtained as link from above which unfortunately no longer exists)
- https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/docs/styleguide/styleguide.html#interface (obtained as link from above which unfortunately no longer exists
- https://codedamn.com/news/reactjs/usestate-hook-typescript (says that you can use type on state but in literally one sentence - no mention of how to instantiate or access the object)

As the project is still in the early phases I'm expecting this object to increase in size. Using a model in this way would greatly simplify having to look up the object keys.

Any help would be much appreciated.

If a (non-working) example would help then let me know and I can quickly put one together.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you considered flow types if TS is not an option? `Is this not the correct way to ensure type specificity in Javascript React projects?` --> No, there used to be `PropTypes`, but nowadays pretty much everyone has either adopted TS or flow, I haven't seen any home-grown type checking solutions in the wild. What exactly do you want to achieve? Something that catches type errors at build or compile time? That would be TS or flow.

Comment: Hi @timotgl. Thanks for your response! Ah bummer. I really wanted it to make use of dot notation so that I can see the exact names of the object's attributes. If I instantiate this object and store it in useState I'm still none the wise and need to look up the database for the attribute names or do a console.log on the object. I think I'll just secretly move over to TS :P