# Property url does not exist on type never Typescript question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm practicing my typescript and having this issue, not quite sure how to set the type for the url when im setting the mix here. The url is going to be a string of course this is in the `handleMix` function:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let options = {
        headers
      }

type Mix = {
    audio_length: number;
    comment_count: number;
    created_time: string;
    favourite_count: number;
    key: string;
    name: string;
    play_count: number;
    repost_count: number;
    url: string;
    user: {
        name: string;
        usernames: string;
    }
}

const Search = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("")
    const [play, setPlay] = useState([])
    const [mix, setMix] = useState<string>("")
    const url = `https://api.mixcloud.com/search/?q=${search}&type=cloudcast`
    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        await fetch(url, options).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data=>setPlay(data.data))
    }

    console.log(play)
    const handleMix = (index:number) => {
        setMix(`https://app.mixcloud.com/oembed/?url=${play[index].url}`)
    }

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-16'>
        <div className='w-[70%] sm:w-[60%] md:w-[50%] flex justify-center'>
        <input type="text" placeholder='Search for a mix...' 
        className='w-[100%] p-4 rounded-l-full outline-none'
        onChange={(e)=>setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit} className='rounded-r-full p-2 bg-slate-600 text-white font-bold text-sm'>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            {play && play.map((mix:Mix,index)=>(
                <div className='cursor-pointer gap-2' key={index}
                onClick={()=>handleMix(index)}
                >
                    <p>{mix.name}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className='m-6 w-[40%]'>
        <iframe width="100%" height="120" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fspartacus%2Fparty-time%2F&amp;hide_cover=1"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

What am I doing wrong. Sorry: I'm new to Typescript and trying to get my head around whenever it screams at me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set types on useState React Hook with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650468/set-types-on-usestate-react-hook-with-typescript)

Answer (score 3):

Inform TypeScript that `play` is an array of `Mix`:

```
const [play, setPlay] = useState<Mix[]>([])
```

Comment: yes that fixed it, thanks. I actually understand typescript way more now